# How to add a custom button to product widget

Tags: magento2

I have create a magento 2 product list grid and I need to add a custom button to the grid as shown below

[image]

Comment: do you want to add it after all product list ?

Comment: @Pawan yeah .. if we use multipel product grids button should be there

Comment: did you added products using widget ?

Comment: @Pawan yes im using widget

Comment: OK, please see my answer and let me know if any issue..

Comment: @Pawan Your solution is working thanks for the help. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you added product using widget, you need to copy below file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

After that you can add a button like:

```
<div class="discover">
    <a href="#">Discover</a>
</div>
```

After div ending with class `block widget block-products-list`

You can also check template by template hint at:

Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer

Change scope to `Store view` from `Default Config`

`Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront` to `Yes`

Hope above will help!

Comment: This solutions  is working as expected.. Thanks

Comment: welcome...Glad to know :)